# Pyinstaller not creating files in Dist Folder

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I installed Pyinstaller successfully. I followed the steps as given here: Using PyInstaller. When I type pyinstaller myscript.py in command window, it creates myscript.spec, the build folder (including myscript.exe.manifest) and the dist folder. However, the dist folder is created as empty. Hence, no myscript.exe file can be found there.
I have download python 3.7 I have already edited my system environment variables....what am I missing?

Comment: ca you be more specific, on your pyinstaller code in cmd. youve to mention if your app is windowed or need to be onefile or icon file all has to be specified i guess, so please specify wt type of project you have inside of myscript.py

Comment: sure....my apologies. I think I actually found a way around it...but not really sure if it is working. The .py file is an android meterpreter shell for a reverse tcp.  I decided to go another route and change the .py to an .apk and then wrapped it with NXcrypt. Once I wrapped it, I then used winrar to hide it with an ico file. I tried to send it to myself through my gmail and noticed gmail caught that there was a virus attached to the ico....so with that message from gmail - I knew the .apk file was recognizable, but when I transfered it to my phone to test it...but never received an open sess

Comment: ty for your reply!

Comment: did it work? cuz u see, .exe is much easier

Comment: unfortunately no...I have decided to revert back to the latest version of VB and installed Veil, this should help with the conversion. Ty for your patience and guidance, very much appreciated, I'm sure you can tell this is a new learning exp for me.